# What does it mean when a function does not return a value?

Tags: c, function

What does it mean when a function does not return a value? How do you state that in a program? How can then a function perform anything useful? whats the meaning with not have any return value?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/283695

Comment: In Pascal there were "procedures" which are basically functions not returning values. Anyway, for such a function to be useful it needs to cause some side-effects (that is - modify some global variables, environment, perform some IO).

Comment: In the C language pointers can be used to modify passed arguments without returning a value from the function. Void functions also might perform other tasks like writing data, pausing execution, etc...

Comment: hm dont understand.  I know how to state that in my program which i did with void but i still can answer the question "What does it mean when a function does not return a value? " i never thought about it so where can I find the answer?

Comment: It means a function doesn't provide a value back to it's caller. E.g. a function declared like `int foo(int bar)` takes an argument of `int` and returns an `int` back, like this: `int x = foo(bar)`. A function `void foo(int bar)` does not return a value in that way.

Comment: It is easier for us to provide an answer if you can illustrate your question with code (and without code your question will likely get closed)

Comment: This question is not too unfocused to answer. The potential effects of a function include returning a value and the side effects listed in C 2018 5.1.2.3 2. So it is a succinct question with a succinct answer.

Comment: What do you expect `printf("hello world\n");` returns? (if you looked it up: if it did not return that, would it still be useful?)

Comment: A function that returns nothing is declared with return value `void`. These functions can **i. e.** do something useful if they manipulate variables that are passed to them as pointers, meaning that they directly manipulate specific memory areas, this is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088406/copying-pointers-and-memory-allocation-confusion/60089712#600897. Functions have their own *scope*, if variables are not passed as pointers functions are only able to manipulate within their local scope or global variables

Comment: @ralfhtp: Functions are permitted by the standard to return nothing without being declared `void`. Besides modifying memory, functions may also access volatile objects and modify files/streams.

Comment: If they return `NULL`, what else possibilities are there ? i wrote the **i.e.** because of the various other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential effects of a function include:

- Returning a value.
- Modifying an object, including either objects the function can access through pointers or objects with external linkage.
- Accessing a volatile object, as above.<sup>1</sup>
- Modifying a file (a stream).

So, if a function does not return a value, it can still modify an object, as in:

```
void SetState(SomeStructure *S, int Value)
{
    S->State = Value;
}
```

or it can modify a stream:

```
void PrintValue(FILE *Stream, int Value)
{
    fprintf(Stream, "%d", Value);
}
```

You can tell the compiler that a function does not return a value by declaring it with return type `void`. However, the C standard also permits functions with non-`void` return types not to return a value. For example, you can have a function that sets or gets a value depending upon a command parameter:

```
int AccessState(int Command, SomeStructure *S,...)
{
    switch (Command)
    {
        case 0: // Get the state.
            return S->Value;
        case 1: // Set the state from the optional int parameter following S.
             va_list ap;
             va_start(ap, S);
             S->Value = va_arg(S, int);
             va_end(ap);
             break;
    }
}
```

In this case, there is no way to tell the compiler that the function sometimes does not return a value, but you do not need to. However, you should tell humans that use and read the code that the function sometimes does and sometimes does not return a value with clear documentation in comments or elsewhere.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Accessing a volatile object is one way for C programs to do things outside the C standard, such as sending commands or data to physical devices.

Answer (score 1):

### What does it mean when a function does not return a value?

It means that that function does not return a value to the caller explicitly.

### How do you state that in a program?

You state it by giving the function a return type of `void`. This return type signifies to the compiler that the function does not return a value.

### How can then a function perform anything useful?

It can perform one or more side-effects as specified in §5.1.2.3 2 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011):

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution environment. *Evaluation* of an expression in general includes both value computations and initiation of side effects. Value computation for an lvalue expression includes determining the identity of the designated object.